# How to consume css in index.html from the endpoint path that returns the css file?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, angularjs, api

My frontend app is running at port http://localhost:3000.

I have an endpoint that returns the css file for specific id(i.e. 88871) as following:

http://localhost:8080/api/getCssFile/88871

I need to add this css file dynamically to head of the index.html file as follows:

```
let cssUrl = "http://localhost:8080/api/getCssFile/" + id;
let link = document.createElement('link');
link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
link.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
link.setAttribute('href', cssUrl);
document.head.appendChild(link);
```

This will add following code to head of the index.html file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080/api/getCssFile/88871" />
```

All looks good. However, Css is not being reflected in the webpage. Css file will be downloaded when this link is clicked instead.

http://localhost:8080/api/getCssFile/88871

Am I missing anything here?

I tried loading css from the api however, the css is not being reflected in the webpage.

Comment: actually you forget extension .css so html can read it,  you want make methods external css you must have extension .css

Comment: Hi! I know this is not an answer to your question, but I'm commenting because I saw the *AngularJS* tag on your post. Note that AngularJS has reached end of support and they advise you to move to Angular2+

https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/version-support-status

Answer (score 0):

The reason your approach is not working is that you are loading the CSS file through JavaScript which runs after your document has already been loaded, so the document does not know about the link as it has already been "painted" by the browser.

I'm not sure why you've chosen the path of having a backend service return a CSS file, but my advice would be to avoid that. If you want shared styling that updates periodically consider creating a NPM library that exposes the stylesheet and consume that within your app.